# Workflow condition for 3 of 6 possible "statuses"

Tags: workflow

i have "STATUS" column, where are 6 possible statuses. The workflow will send e-mail only if there is selected Status "1","2", or "4".
How to write the condition: Send e-mail IF status = 1 OR 2 OR 4 ??
Now i have 3 conditions and it is not the best way i think.
Thak you
Milan

Answer (score 1):

Add a Calculated Column that decides if to send the email, and have the workflow test the Calculated Column

```
=IF( OR( [Status]=1, [Status]=2, [Status]=4 ), "Send an email", "no email for you" )
```

A side benefit is that the rules for sending email can be changed without editing the workflow, and that the workflow is identical for multiple lists, even if the rules for each list are different. Just edit the Calculated Column.